# Dash - Upload CSV and render graphs

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I'm new to Dash and trying to learn how to do what seems like a very trivial function: upload a CSV and use it as a dataframe.  Most of the examples show referencing a local csv file.  I'm not sure what the next step is to have Dash reference the data I've uploaded in CSV.  The code I've written so far allows the user to upload the CSV file and it renders a table.  The next thing should be to select specific columns from the CSV file and generate a simple line graph.  Any advice is appreciated!

```
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash

import plotly
import dash_table_experiments as dte
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import json
import datetime
import operator
import os

import base64
import io

app = dash.Dash()

app.scripts.config.serve_locally = True
app.config['suppress_callback_exceptions'] = True

app.layout = html.Div([

 html.H5("Upload Files"),
 dcc.Upload(
    id='upload-data',
    children=html.Div([
        'Drag and Drop or ',
        html.A('Select Files')
    ]),
    style={
        'width': '100%',
        'height': '60px',
        'lineHeight': '60px',
        'borderWidth': '1px',
        'borderStyle': 'dashed',
        'borderRadius': '5px',
        'textAlign': 'center',
        'margin': '10px'
    },
    multiple=False),


html.Br(),
html.H5('filename'),
html.Div(dte.DataTable(rows=[{}], id='table'))

])


# Functions

# file upload function
def parse_contents(contents, filename):
content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')

decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
try:
    if 'csv' in filename:
        # Assume that the user uploaded a CSV file
        df = pd.read_csv(
            io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf-8')))
    elif 'xls' in filename:
        # Assume that the user uploaded an excel file
        df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded))

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    return None

return df


# callback table creation
@app.callback(Output('table', 'rows'),
          [Input('upload-data', 'contents'),
           Input('upload-data', 'filename')])
def update_output(contents, filename):
    if contents is not None:
        df = parse_contents(contents, filename)
        if df is not None:
        return df.to_dict('records')
           else:
             return [{}]
    else:
      return [{}]

# callback Graph Creation - not sure how to reference the csv file that was 
uploaded.  Just want to create a simple line graph or scatter plot with two 
of the variables in the file


app.css.append_css({
   "external_url": "https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css"
})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: Hello, did you ever figure this out on how to upload a CSV & plot the data?

Comment: let me find the code - yes, I think I came up with a solution

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I clicked the link and an access request was sent using my gmail address

Comment: should work now.

Comment: Looking for a similar solution, but can't view it on the drive. Have requested for permission.

Comment: I've created a new post regarding this issue:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57677709/why-is-dash-giving-a-parse-error-when-uploading-files   
if anyone has suggestions, that would be great.  I can't seem to get uploading to work any more, and I also cannot implement a dynamic drop-down based on the uploaded file.

Comment: I want to read a CSV file and then use it as the usual DataFrame we use in python. How do I do that? Can you share your code here too?