# Why is Dash giving a parse error when uploading files?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

Uploading Excel or CSV results in an error.  I followed the Dash demo, but as soon as I try to extend it to do something like plotting, it doesn't work.  I don't want to just show a table.  The Dash_Table function was updated, so previous examples that used Dash_Table_Experiments no longer work

I've spent the whole night on stack exchange, tinkering with my code and reading other solutions.  the full working code is provided below.   I'd like to also add a drop down call back function to "filter" the data by a categorical variable.

```
 import base64
 import datetime
 import io
 import plotly.graph_objs as go
 import dash
 from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
 import dash_core_components as dcc
 import dash_html_components as html
 import dash_table

 import pandas as pd


 external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

 app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

 app.layout = html.Div([
  dcc.Upload(
      id='upload-data',
      children=html.Div([
        'Drag and Drop or ',
        html.A('Select Files')
    ]),
    style={
        'width': '100%',
        'height': '60px',
        'lineHeight': '60px',
        'borderWidth': '1px',
        'borderStyle': 'dashed',
        'borderRadius': '5px',
        'textAlign': 'center',
        'margin': '10px'
    },
    # Allow multiple files to be uploaded
    multiple=False
  ),
  html.Div(id='output-data-upload'),
  dcc.Graph(id='graph1')
 ])


 def parse_contents(contents, filename):
   content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')

   decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)

   try:
       if 'csv' in filename:
         # Assume that the user uploaded a CSV file
          df = pd.read_csv(
            io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf-8')))
       elif 'xls' in filename:
          # Assume that the user uploaded an excel file
          df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded))
   except Exception as e:
       print(e)
       return html.Div([
           'There was an error processing this file.'
       ])

return html.Div([
    html.H5(filename),
    # html.H6(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(date)),

    dash_table.DataTable(
        data=df.to_dict('records'),
        columns=[{'name': i, 'id': i} for i in df.columns]
    ),

    html.Hr(),  # horizontal line
    # For debugging, display the raw contents provided by the web browser
    html.Div('Raw Content'),
    html.Pre(contents[0:200] + '...', style={
        'whiteSpace': 'pre-wrap',
        'wordBreak': 'break-all'
    })
 ])


 @app.callback(Output('output-data-upload', 'children'),
          [Input('upload-data', 'contents')],
          [State('upload-data', 'filename')])
 def update_output(list_of_contents, list_of_names):
   if list_of_contents is not None:
       children = [
           parse_contents(c, n) for c, n in
           zip(list_of_contents, list_of_names)]
      return children

@app.callback(
   Output('graph1', 'figure'),
   [Input('upload-data', 'contents'),
   Input('upload-data', 'filename')])

def plot_graph(contents, filename):
   df = parse_contents(contents, filename)
   trace1 = go.Bar(
        x=df['Quarter'],
        y=df['Score'],
    )

layout = go.Layout(
    title='graph1'

)
fig = go.Figure(data = [trace1], layout=layout)
return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run_server(debug=True)
```

The error I get is: Callback error updating output-data-upload.children: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

and

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

The problem appears to be with how python is handling the parser:

```
  def parse_contents(contents, filename):
     content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')

   decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
```

But none of the solutions seem to resolve the problem.

please help.  Since so many people are struggling with this (it would seem), it would be great if we could resolve it and post a functioning code (Github?) that accomplishes what Shiny can so easily do already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code:

```
   children = [
       parse_contents(c, n) for c, n in
       zip(list_of_contents, list_of_names)]
```

And then

```py
def parse_contents(contents, filename):
    content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')
    decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
    ...
```

Here the error happens when `c` in None, then the `contents` parameter of `parse_contents` is None, and the "None has no .split" error happens.

If `c` is not None but only has one word, then `contents.split()` returns just one element, and the "not enough values to unpack" error happens.

I would filter it:

```py
pairs = zip(list_of_contents, list_of_names)
children = [parse_contents(c, n) for (c, n) in pairs if c and (len(c.split(',')) == 2)]
```

You could also consider doing the split outside `parse_contents` and change the code around it.

I would also try to log the filenames for which contents wrong, e.g. `[n for (c, n) in pairs if not c or len(c.split(',')) != 2])`.

Comment: Thank you for a very fast reply. so you are suggesting: 
`def update_output(list_of_contents, list_of_names):`
`if list_of_contents is not None:`
`pairs = zip(list_of_contents, list_of_names)`
`children = [parse_contents(c, n) for c, n in pairs if c] return children`

Comment: because I tried this code, and I'm getting the same error.

Comment: I extended my answer for extra cases.

Comment: Thank you.  This resolved it.  However, as a result, I'm getting a callback error for the plotting callback function.  Shouldn't the callback recognize the column headers in the dataframe object?  There are 3 columns: "Brand", "Quarter", and "Score" 

def plot_graph(contents, filename):
   df = parse_contents(contents, filename)
   trace1 = go.Bar(
        x=df['Quarter'],
        y=df['Score'],
    )

Comment: that maybe related to this error:  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Wherever you do a `.split()` and expect multiple results, you may end up with that error if actual splitting does not produce the exactly expected number of parts. I don't know what your data look like, but _three_ columns, like `Brand,Quarter,Score` will produce 3, not 2, values if split. A more complete example would be needed. (Also, debug-printing everything involved helps spot the problem immensely.)

Comment: Thank you.  I'll work on and see what I can discover.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.  Posting here for others to make use of:

```
def parse_contents(contents, filename):
if contents is not None:
    content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')

    decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)

    try:
        if 'csv' in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded a CSV file
            df = pd.read_csv(
                io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf-8')))
        elif 'xlsx' in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded an excel file
            df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return html.Div([
            'There was an error processing this file.'
        ])

    return df
else:
    return [{}]


@app.callback(Output('table', 'data'),
              [Input('upload-data', 'contents'),
              Input('upload-data', 'filename')])
def update_output(contents, filename):
    if contents is not None:
        df = parse_contents(contents, filename)
        if df is not None:
            return df.to_dict('records')
        else:
            return [{}]
    else:
        return [{}]
@app.callback(
    Output('graph1', 'figure'),
    [Input('upload-data', 'contents'),
     Input('upload-data', 'filename')])

def plot_graph(contents, filename):
    df = parse_contents(contents, filename)
    trace1 = go.Bar(
            x=df['Quarter'],
            y=df['Score'],
        )

    layout = go.Layout(
        title='graph1'

)
fig = go.Figure(data = [trace1], layout=layout)
return fig
```